# How give back "Console" tab in "Version Controll" in Intellij Idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have closed `Console` tab in `Version Control` in Intellij Idea. How opened it again?[image]

**P.S.** Very hard to google, really. Console means terminal client and SSH integration or results aboout git configuration are given.

Comment: Could you try `alt + 9`?

Comment: Do not know why, but WORKS !!!! oO Many thanks tfor quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

[donquih0te](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8498513/donquih0te) wrote [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614301/how-give-back-console-tab-in-version-controll-in-intellij-idea/60614568#comment107237356_60614301) which suggested <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> and resolved the issue.